# Find last commit just before a FF merge

Tags: git

Is it possible to find the previous branch tip after a FF merge? In my case the new branch tip is a merge commit and there is a whole topology added from this FF merge but do not think that matters. My issue is to find out the commit before applying the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not findable from the *commit graph*.

If Git still retains the previous commit hash in the relevant *reflogs*, it *is* findable from the reflogs.

Reflogs are specific to *one particular clone*, so if the fast-forward happened in some other clone, you cannot use this method to find the previous hash ID.  If the fast-forward happened in *your* clone, you can.  Use `git reflog branch-name` to view the reflog, which will show stuff like this:

```
$ git reflog master
b994622632 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) master@{0}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
b34789c0b0 master@{1}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
d61d20c9b4 master@{2}: merge refs/remotes/origin/master: Fast-forward
...
```

Each of those hash IDs is one of the hash IDs that `refs/heads/master` held in the past, or (for `master@{0}`) holds now.  So usually `name@{1}` is the one you would want here.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the git host you're using and the way you work, your host may have recorded the pushes. If your target branch was up to date with your remote, you merge ant then you push, then the push history will show you a nice picture:

Example from Azure Devops:

[image]